# How to avoid document.write on a media query

Tags: javascript

I try to avoid using `document.write` on a media query. Any suggestions?

```
<script>
  if (screen && screen.width > 601) {
    document.write('<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""><\/script>');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually create a `script` element and then append it.

```js
const scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT');

console.log(scripts);
```

```html
<script>
  if (screen && screen.width > 601) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js";
    script.integrity = "sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==";
    script.crossOrigin = "";
    document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].appendChild(script);
  }
</script>
```

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Ernesto, thanks for your reply. No, unfortunately it doesn't work. It doesn't seem to load.

Comment: @maxLL I've just updated my answer with a snippet and it seems to work. Please remember that the order of `script` elements matter. I think the problem is not with the above code.